# Text is getting cut-off (hyphenated) while browsing pages

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress is cutting off the text, and I would like to know if it is possible to turn this off, or fix it.

Example, if text width does not fit the page width, instead of moving next word to new line, Wordpress is cutting off half of the word

The sentence:     `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog system"`

Should be (if it does not fit the width):

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

system
```

What happens:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog sys-
tem
```

The word `system`, for example, is being cut-off.

Comment: Is the word cut off, or is it hyphenated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, CSS is the culprit (using TwentyTwelve?), find e.g.:

```
.site-content article {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

replace with:

```
.site-content article {
    word-wrap: normal;
    -webkit-hyphens: none;
    -moz-hyphens: none;
    hyphens: none;
}
```